# How to call c++ method inside objective C

Tags: objective-c

I made some method in pseudo code, and I want to create objective C method. Could you help me define it? I am not very familiar with objective C, so I am confused. Also, I want to use strings as parameters for the method, but not NSString objects.

this is the method definition. I am not sure if it fits objective C definitions and also I am unsure about the type "string".

```
-(BOOL) testMethod(string largestring, string smallstring) {
    return true;
}
```

And do I have to include some library so I can use string type? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you want to use *strings* as parameters, so I assume you don't want C-style `char*` but some sort of string class. Since you didn't specify anything else, in my example I am using `std::string` from the C++ standard library.

This is how your method looks like in Objective-C syntax:

```
#import <string>

- (BOOL) testMethodWithLargeString:(const std::string&)largeString smallString:(const std::string&)smallString
{
  return YES;
}
```

Some notes:

- To make this work you must place this in a file with the extension `.mm`. The extension tells the compiler that the file contains mixed C++ and Objective-C code
- `std::string` comes from the C++ standard library, but I believe you do not have to do anything special to make your project link against that library.
- You must decide whether you want to use `BOOL` (uppercase) or `bool` (lowercase) as your return type. `BOOL` is the traditional Objective-C boolean type, whereas `bool` is the traditional C++ primitive boolean type. With `BOOL` you must use `YES` and `NO` as return values, whereas with `bool` you must use `true` and `false`. You should not try to mix the two types and their values, it will not make the compiler happy (and if you use casts to force the compiler to accept the mix, sooner or later *you* will not be happy)
- Try to stick to `const std::string&` as the type for your `in` parameters. The `const` will save you from accidentally changing the content of your parameters. If you use just `std::string&` (without the `const`) the parameter becomes an `out` parameter. I also recommend you do not use pointers (i.e. `const std::string*` or `std::string*`) because `std::string` is a value type (read up on that topic if it is unfamiliar) and thus is usually combined with references. Last but not least: Never *ever* use `std::string` (i.e. without `&` [reference] or `*` [pointer]) - if you do, a *copy* of the string will be created each time you invoke the method. If you already know about all these things, then of course you can ignore my advice :-)
- A final word in regard to the naming of the method: It is a peculiarity of Objective-C that method names are split up in "sections", one for each parameter. This has the advantage that you can build parameter names right into the method name, with the result that when you invoke methods the code is much more expressive and clearer to read. A similar feature in other languages are named parameters (aka keyword arguments).

The answer by Maxthon Chan also has useful hints about what you need to take into account when you mix C++ and Objective-C.

Comment: Well as an additional note, make sure your file extension is `.mm` (maybe `.mpp`?) or clang will complain. Also, a better looking solution is to use a set of inline functions to do the conversion. You can `typedef struct objc_object *NSString` in C++ code to prevent C++ compiler from complaining.

Answer (score 3):

Well here are multiple ways:

1. In your C++ code, provide wrapper functions of your C++ methods in C, with `extern "C"`.
2. Name your Objective-C code with `.mm` extension (that is, Objective-C++) and call C++ directly.

There is some limitations:

- Objective-C cannot catch C++ exceptions and in earlier versions C++ cannot catch Objective-C exceptions too.
- In earlier versions, C++ destructors are not called when an object is released. You need to manually do that in `-(void) dealloc`.
- You cannot put C++ objects into Objective-C containers.

And a good point:

- In Objective-C++ code, you can mix C++11 lambda expression with Objective-C blocks - with clang 3.3 they are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Your method should be like this

```
-(BOOL) testMethodWithLargeString:(NSString *)largestring smallString(NSString *)smallstring {
    return YES;
}
```

For accessing this method :

```
BOOL result = [<classObject> testMethodWithLargeString:string1 smallString:string2];
```

If the method is in self class, use `self` otherwise you need to use an object or class.

Also, a convention of writing multiple parameterized method, (breaking it into multiple line) :

```
BOOL result = [<classObject> testMethodWithLargeString:string1 
                                           smallString:string2];
```

---

> And do I have to include some library so I can use string type?

**NO**, You dont have to use any library like string.h

In cocoa Foundation framework all these are included.

Answer (score 1):

**Sample Code :**

```
-(BOOL) testMethod :(NSString *)largestring :(NSString *)smallstring {
    return YES;
}
```

---

**Explanation :** Check [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/).

[image]

**Use :**
`[self testMethod :yourLargeString :yourSmallString];`

---

> And do I have to include some library so I can use string type ?

- **Answer : No.** Actually, `NSString.h` is declared inside `Foundation.framework` and `Xcode` by default adds this framework to your Project when you creates new one (Check inside **Frameworks** folder). So, you have implicitly added that Library and that's why no need to include specific `NSString` class.